# Estou com problemas ao ordenar os aniversariantes do mês no Eloquent do Laravel 5.7

Tags: laravel, laravel-eloquent

Minha consulta retorna os aniversariantes corretamente, mas ao ordenar pela coluna da tabela ele ordena pelo ano e no pelo dia.

> Esta é a minha query

```
$birthday = \App\Admin\Clients::whereMonth('birthday', \Carbon\Carbon::now()->month)
                  ->orderBy('birthday', 'asc')->get();
```

tentei usar um array na ordenação desta forma `orderBy(['DAY', 'birthday'], 'asc')`, mas só posso usar o nome da coluna.

Tentei com `WhereBetween`, mas sem sucesso também. Existem outras formas de fazer este tipo de ordenação?

Comment: `birthday` é qual tipo de valor?

Comment: É campo `DATE` no banco de dados

Comment: estranho cara `orderBy('birthday')`, mas, é que você pega também os anos aleatórios neh? se quer pegar como, explica? porque só está filtrando por mês, !

Comment: Você achou a solução, mas, não entendeu bem pra que serve... tem um adendo na sua resposta nos comentários

Comment: Amanhã vou editar a resposta para melhorar a compreensão minha e de todos.

Comment: Leia isso: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#raw-methods

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É mais simples do que eu estava imaginando, bastou apenas trocar `orderBy('birthday')` por:

```
orderByRaw('day(birthday) asc')
```

> Como funciona as claulas com terminação `Raw`

Ela faz a consulta bruta ao banco de dados, ou seja você pode fazer a mesma como se estivesse consultando sem os métodos mágicos do `Eloquent`, veja alguns exemplos.

**Caso queira usar um `IF` na query**

```
DB::table('clients')
          ->selectRaw('IF(name = "ana", ?, ANA)')
          ->get();
```

> Conforme documentao em https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#raw-methods

**Conforme documentação é possível usar `Raw` em:**

- `selectRaw( )`
- `whereRaw( )`
- `havingRaw( ) / orHavingRaw( )`
- `orderByRaw( )`

Comment: é escrito na própria `SQL` o comando no caso na clausula `order by`, todos os métodos que terminam com `Raw` no `Builder` faz esse papel ... entendi o que você queria

Comment: ordenar um campo date irá considerar data completa. Isso inclui o ano também, ordenando dos mais antigo até o mais novo. A ordenação que você deseja é a partir do dia somente.